# php code inside variable with html code

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to add code php to variable with html, for example

```
$html = '<b></b> <?php echo $lang["text"] ?>';
```

but it don't interpret php code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use string concatenations like this:

```
$html = '<b></b>' . $lang['text'];
```

or insert variable in double quoted string like this:

```
$html = "<b></b>${lang['text']}";
```

both versions are correct, use the one that you like.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is called string interpolation (read about [how it works for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)).

Your particular example would be solved using

```
$html = "<b></b> {$lang['text']}";
```

String interpolation only happens in double quoted string (`"string here"`).

Answer (score 3):

its very important to escape the output. (security basics)

```
$html = sprintf('<b>%s</b>', htmlspecialchars($lang['text']));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$html = '<b>'.$lang['text'].'</b>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch from "Output raw text mode" to "Run PHP code mode" in the middle of a string **while you are already in "Run PHP code mode"**

```
$html = "<b></b> ${lang['text']}";
```

… although why you want an empty bold element is beyond me.

Comment: Judging by the question, this answer is not something the poster will understand.. This is a comment rather than an answer imho.

Answer (score -5):

make sure file extension is php.

```
<?php
     $html = '<b>' . $lang["text"] . '</b>';
?>
```

Comment: I believe this is even worse than the actual question.